# How do you check if 2 OffsetDateTime lie within another 2 OffsetDateTIme?

Tags: c#, nodatime

Given an POCO Event{OffsetDateTime Start, OffsetDateTime End} and a POCO Trial {OffsetDateTime Start, OffsetDateTime End}

Where trials typical span hours, and events happen over a few seconds.

How can I test whether an Event happened within a Trial?

The Naive code that came before, used: event.Start > trial.Start && event.Start < trial.End

but converting to NodaTime those comparisons are no longer valid.

I suspect I can't without making some assumptions about how it should be converted to instants and intervals, considering both Event and Trial come from a third party library, that should probably be using timezoned types, or instants rather then OffsetDateTimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this answer aims at "trial completely contains event" - for "trial overlaps event", see Matt Johnson's answer.

`OffsetDateTime.ToInstant` is unambiguous, so you could certainly just convert to `Instant` values. You might want to create an interval from the trial though:

```
Interval trial = new Interval(trial.Start.ToInstant(), trial.End.ToInstant());

if (trial.Contains(event.Start.ToInstant()) &&
    trial.Contains(event.End.ToInstant()))
{
    ...
}
```

One potential wrinkle of this is that the end point of an interval is exclusive... so if `event.End` and `trial.End` are the same instant, the above will not enter the `if` statement body.

Comment: Cheers Jon, I think the previous code would have run into the same issues right?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: Well, you weren't showing what you were using for the end part, so it's hard to know - but potentially, yes. You definitely want to think about (and test) edge cases like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet - This only tests if the entire length of the event is within the trial.  Perhaps that's what the OP wanted, but it seems like maybe they were actually wanting a test for overlapping ranges, as per my answer.  Maybe a good case for an `IntersectsWith` or `OverlapsWith` method on `Interval`?

Comment: @MattJohnson: I got the impression it was the former - but you're right that it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but it seems you were wanting to know if the `trial` and the `event` *overlapped*.  Assuming that your ranges are half-open intervals (inclusive start, exclusive end) - then you would test for overlap with:

```
if (trial.Start.ToInstant() < event.End.ToInstant() &&
    trial.End.ToInstant() > event.Start.ToInstant())
{
    ...
}
```